# Capifony error during deployment (OpenSSL::PKey::PKeyError: not a public key "/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")

Tags: capistrano, ssh-keys, capifony

I keep getting this error `(OpenSSL::PKey::PKeyError: not a public key "/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")`

Thanks in advance.

My deploy.rb looks like this:

```
  set :application, "goom"
    set :domain,      "goom@bloom.com"
    set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/goom"
    #set :app_path,    "app"

    set :repository,  "/var/www/goom/.git"
    set :scm,         :git
    set :deploy_via,  :copy
    # Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `subversion`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, $

    set :model_manager, "doctrine"
    # Or: `propel`

    role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
    role :app,        domain                         # This may be the same as your$
    role :db,         domain, :primary => true       # This is where Rails migratio$
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turnes out that it is a format issue. Originally my public key had the following format:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20101206"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQB80B66jlf+Xo3E0d6TJdojKB1mkblUCjyCaOA1
p2GpvQr+TjtCugdmh9069ybWcJCaRcvJu12pz/0iO8H0Ar/f3AiULaj6VHF9rdkA
qp+k+Ih0ep204VENqgobGfDOKfBcd2o9P1zdbCuie28tGSxoQMZNVVPMXPgl80HQ
v8+dqL4YDEvsViOMa/A1pxlvw74XwU6jzaVM+4u2ysKu0xEJzSUR4wT4s7f0zr3G
FNZDlj0vmuyggo9/3BIgtAQC9IcALqT5Jf3V5iN03+8uPUJVuy+XvIJoZJo5fnrT
zXzDBdUmjJNt+zTYsX3/fHQZOxokHPiBQQ5OTL+NW1Uscukv
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

Reformatting it to the following did the trick:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQB80B66jlf+Xo3E0d6TJdojKB1mkblUCjyCaOA1p2GpvQr+TjtCugdmh9069ybWcJCaRcvJu12pz/0iO8H0Ar/f3AiULaj6VHF9rdkAqp+k+Ih0ep204VENqgobGfDOKfBcd2o9P1zdbCuie28tGSxoQMZNVVPMXPgl80HQv8+dqL4YDEvsViOMa/A1pxlvw74XwU6jzaVM+4u2ysKu0xEJzSUR4wT4s7f0zr3GFNZDlj0vmuyggo9/3BIgtAQC9IcALqT5Jf3V5iN03+8uPUJVuy+XvIJoZJo5fnrTzXzDBdUmjJNt+zTYsX3/fHQZOxokHPiBQQ5OTL+NW1Uscukv
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

As you can see in the first line:

```
(OpenSSL::PKey::PKeyError: not a public key "/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
```

Ruby claims to be looking in the /var/www/.ssh folder... it's not.

It's actually defaulting... for whatever insane reason... to /var/www/ So all I did was copy id_rsa and id_rsa.pub to /var/www and it ran just fine.

Never actually got it to DEPLOY mind you... (I eventually used Git for that)... but I did get past this error!